# Maximum Allowed Order Weight

Tags: magento-1.6, shopping-cart

I have to put condition for maximum allowd order weight. Have you any ideas about this please answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What should happen if the weight is too high?

In [Thebod_Shippingrates](https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates) you can define conditions based on the weight. If no condition is met, no shipping options is shown. Not nice, though.